# Javascript - need to identifiy strings that contains more then just the 2 brackets signs ()

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am looking for a specific regular expression that will help me identify if my string contains only 2 types of characters -

The regular expression that I need should identify if a specific string contains only the brackets characters `(` `)`

Comment: What have you tried already? It sounds like a very basic IF expression... if string contains "(" and if string contains ")" then ok, else not ok.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose: This is obviously not correct. Both conditions are true if the string contains at least one of each symbol, but they remain true if there are other characters in the string, too.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Not if you nest your IF statements properly.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose: OK, given the string `"(x)"`, how would you nest your `if` statements?

Comment: @TimPietzcker something along the lines of... IF(string contains "("; IF(string contains ")";) - note that looking at the answers below this is obviously a long way about doing it, but nesting of IF statements would work.

Comment: Basically, if it contains "(" return true else return false, if the first answer is true then test to see if it contains ")" and again, return true or false. If both test at true then you know if contains both "(" and ")" otherwise it does not.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose: But that's not the question. The question is how to make sure that the string *does not contain any other characters* besides `()`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker ahhh well, the question was edited since I left my comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
/^[()]+$/
```

Note that this does *not* check if the parentheses are in balanced pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regular exception is what you're looking for :

```
^[()]*$
```

Replace the * by a + to if you want to be sure there is at least one character in your string.